# Can you give me a visual representation on 1/6 of 4/5 to get 4/30?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

I'm trying to understand fractions more by using a visual representation, and I having a hard time making a visual representation of the 1/6 of 4/5 and getting a visual understandable representation of the answer 4/30.

I'd appreciate If somebody could represent it for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at the following grid:[image]

Suppose you want to take $\frac{1}{6}$ of it, then just take one of the rows, as shown in the following drawing:

[image]

Now, suppose we only want $\frac{4}{5}$ of that $\frac{1}{6}$. Then just take $4$ of the $5$ squares that make up that row:

[image]

At the end we ended up with $4$ squares, while the entire grid has a total of $30$. therefore $\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{4}{5}=\frac{4}{30}$

Comment: How can I make the images smaller?

Comment: You could do something without graphics, like $$\begin{array}{ccccc} X&X&X&X&O\\O&O&O&O&O\\O&O&O&O&O\\O&O&O&O&O\\O&O&O&O&O\\O&O&O&O&O\end{array}$$

Comment: Or, even better, $$\begin{array}{ccccc} \blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\blacksquare&\square\\ \square&\square&\square&\square&\square\\ \square&\square&\square&\square&\square\\ \square&\square&\square&\square&\square\\ \square&\square&\square&\square&\square\\ \square&\square&\square&\square&\square\end{array}$$

Comment: Now all that's left is to explain why the word "of" translates into multiplication.

Comment: @MPW that's nice, how did you do it?

Comment: Right-click and select "Show as LaTeX commands", you can see it. Its basically an array filled with \square and \blacksquare items

Answer (score 5):

Divide a cake into $30$ equal slices. $\frac45$ of the cake is represented by $\frac45\times 30=24$ slices. $\frac16$ of these $24$ slices is $\frac16\times 24=4$ slices, which is also $\frac{4}{30}$ of the whole cake.

Comment: Jasper Loy is a curious individual. In every 30-day month, he eats a hamburger every day, except when the day is divisible by 5. Every 6th time he eats a hamburger, he adds cheese.

At the end of the month, he will have eaten 4 hamburgers with cheese.

Comment: Good job people - now you have me hungry :(

Answer (score 2):

Take 15 squares and shade 12 of them. Then you have shaded 4/5 of the squares. Now divide the 12 shaded squares into 6 equal pieces. Then each piece consists of two squares. So two squares represents 1/6 of 4/5 and two squares out of 15 squares equals 4/30.